# how to retrive data from Json objecj or Array and update a drop down using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying this for quite sometime searching different post here..but could not get the concept on how get data/value from a JSON object or Array

I am using Gson to convert my ArrayList to JSON.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
Gson gson=new Gson();
JsonObject myobj=new JsonObject();
JsonElement element=gson.toJsonTree(owningOrgRecords);
    myobj.add("owningorg", element);
   out.print( myobj.toString());
 //i tried this too String teamJSON=gson.toJson(owningOrgRecords); and out.print(teamJSON).
```

Out put i get when i use myobj.toString()

JSON Object

```
{
"owningorg": [
    {
        "owning_org_id": 157,
        "owning_org_desc": "FirstOwning Org",
        "team": "SSSB Team",
        "created_on": "TodayDate",
        "created_by": "Adminuser"
    },
    {
        "owning_org_id": 158,
        "owning_org_desc": "SecondOwning Org",
        "team": "SSSB Team",
        "created_on": "TodayDate",
        "created_by": "Adminuser"
    },
    {
        "owning_org_id": 159,
        "owning_org_desc": "ThirdOwning Org",
        "team": "SSSB Team",
        "created_on": "TodayDate",
        "created_by": "Adminuser"
    }
]
```

}

JSON Array

```
[
{
    "owning_org_id": 157,
    "owning_org_desc": "FirstOwning Org",
    "team": "SSSB Team",
    "created_on": "TodayDate",
    "created_by": "Adminuser"
},
{
    "owning_org_id": 158,
    "owning_org_desc": "SecondOwning Org",
    "team": "SSSB Team",
    "created_on": "TodayDate",
    "created_by": "Adminuser"
},
{
    "owning_org_id": 159,
    "owning_org_desc": "ThirdOwning Org",
    "team": "SSSB Team",
    "created_on": "TodayDate",
    "created_by": "Adminuser"
}
```

]

Java scripts i currently have.

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"myServlet",
        cache:false,
        data:a,
        success:function(html){
            console.debug(html);
            var jsonList=html.owningorg;
            alert(jsonList.owningorg.lenght);
            $("#owningorg").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#owningorg").html("");
        for(var i=0;i<jsonList.lenght;i++){

            listItems+="<option value='" + jsonList.owningorg[i].owning_org_id + "'>" + jsonList.owningorg[i].owning_org_dec[i] + "</option>";

            } 



        }
    });
```

My question is how to get the owning_org_dec and Owning_org_id populate into Value and desc of a drop Using Jquery. i currently get null values into dropdown. Please explain me on how to retrieve data from a JSON Object and JSON Array into dropdown or points to a post or tutorial. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
var thisVal = jsonList.owningorg[i].owning_org_id;
var thisTxt = jsonList.owningorg[i].owning_org_dec[i];
$("<option />").attr("value", yourvalue).text(thisTxt).appendTo("#NAMEofSelect");
```

keep in mind that you have to pass the name of the Select Field you want to appendTo. (#NameofSelect)

Comment: when i tried this firebug is showing me following error---- TypeError: jsonList.owningorg is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

var thisVal = jsonList.owningorg[1].owning_org_id;